# Skip first leg of a flight but still check-in in point A

Tags: layovers

I'm from YUM. There's a 8h30 layover before the flight to CLT. Can I skip the first leg YUM - PHX, check-in in YUM and drive to PHX and catch the PHX - CLT - YUL flights?

Reason :
Trip A-B-C-D is :
YUM - PHX - ( 8h30 layover ) - CLT - YUL
Price : 400$

Trip B-C-D is : 
PHX - CLT - YUL
Price : 620$

Comment: Where you check is in irrelevant - the answer is the same

Comment: You may want to look up "hidden city ticketing" for details.

Answer (score 3):

The moment you abandon the first segment, rest of your itinerary, including return ticket (in same itenary) will be cancelled.

If you want to avoid the 8.5 hour layover, only option is to pay higher.

Comment: Also, if the check-in includes checking in baggage, it will not be transported without the passenger, so the baggage will be offloaded before the no-show on the first flight segement. For safety reasons, baggage will not be transported without the passenger due to reasons for which the airline is not responsible.